# Cannot import Firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an existing Firebase project that I am trying to import into the new Firebase 3.0 version that was just released at Google I/O 2016. Every time I try to import it, I keep getting this error with no helpful message on how to fix it or what the actual problem is.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It Sometimes related to your extensions that you have added them before for example I had `Enable Cross Origin *` Extension and Firebase did nothing at all.

Comment: for me it was the "Disconnect" Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you've had trouble! No open-and-shut answer here, but some things you can check:

1. Firebase has been popular this week, so we've had a fair bit of load. Try importing the project again and see if it works.
2. There is a known issue where projects with very short names may not import. That's being worked on - so if you have one of those projects, please check in later!
3. A Firebase project in the new console is also a Google Developers/Google Cloud console project. There is a limit to how many of those you can have.

To check if its the third case, try going to http://console.developers.google.com and see how many projects you have. If its a few (double digits) you may be hitting this issue. You can delete any unused projects and then try and import again. Unfortunately you may have to wait a bit as projects can be un-deleted, so the slot isn't made available immediately.

If none of this fits you, then it may be something new! Try filing a ticket with the support team and include the details of your project: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: I'm having the same issues :( Driving me mad.. i think the name is too short "100hh" others in my account have migrated fine.

Comment: Ah I wonder if that one might be due to starting with a number. Can you file a ticket with the support team if you haven't already? https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: @IanBarber, its neither of the 3 options you mentioned above. The project I had created is registered from my google apps email, could that be the problem ? Also its not live yet and is still in development.

Comment: Apps email should work, as long as you're logging in to the new console with the same account.