# Firebase 3.0 create new project operation forbidden and project import error

Tags: firebase-hosting

I had a firebase account setup last year and now I need to work on an app that was hosted there. If I want to add a new project I get the error message 'Your operation was forbidden' and if I import the project to the new firebase environment I get the error 'There was an error when importing the project'.

Just in case this might interfere, I replaced the firebase rules of the project by the default

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

The alternative is not to upgrade to Firebase 3.0 but then I cannot use firebase-tools anymore (error 'This version of the Firebase CLI is only compatible with
projects that have been upgraded to the new Firebase Console. To access your
firebase.com apps, use a previous version: npm install -g firebase-tools@^2.1) and after doing so I still get that message. (Or: how should I after that run a command like 'firebase list' making sure I'm using the old firebase command instead of the new one?)

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347203/cannot-import-firebase-project). Issue unresolved? I checked for the cloud projects on this account: this is the only one.

I need to have the app up and running short term so please provide a solution or work-around?

Comment: Have similar issue, and have contacted the Firebase team still no positive response from them.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this link](https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat/issues/74), try

```
firebase use --add
```

then

```
firebase deploy
```

For me, it worked.